# How to fill netplan config file with routes via ansible

Tags: loops, templates, variables, ansible, netplan

I'm trying  to manage netplan by using ansible. That worked well in the past, where I used the following template:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    {{ ansible_default_ipv4.interface }}:
      match:
          macaddress: {{ ansible_default_ipv4.macaddress }}
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
  bridges:
    br0:
      macaddress: {{ ansible_default_ipv4.macaddress }}
      interfaces:
        - {{ ansible_default_ipv4.interface }}
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}/32]
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: {{ ansible_default_ipv4.gateway }}
          on-link: true
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - {{ DNS1 }}
          - {{ DNS2 }}
          - {{ DNS3 }}
```

Now I have to add several lines to the route section:

```
...
  bridges:
    br0:
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: {{ ansible_default_ipv4.gateway }}
          on-link: true
        - to: {{ IP1 }}/32
          scope: link
        - to: {{ IP2 }}/32
          scope: link
...
```

Now here comes the part, where I struggle.

Due to the fact, that my local routes differs from host to host, I can't use a static template. So I tried to create a list in the host vars file, that contains a list of ips.

```
ROUTES:
  - ip: "aaa.AAA.aaa.AAA"
  - ip: "bbb.BBB.bbb.BBB"
  - ip: "ccc.CCC.ccc.CCC"
  - ip :"...."
  - n
```

I wanted to insert this list into my netplan file while looping over this list.

But I dont get it working. Do you have any hint or advice?
Thx in advance

Comment: its not clear, you want to replace IP1 by aaa.AAA.aaa.AAA, IP2 by bbbb.... and so on  in your routes key?

Comment: The two lines beginning with "-to:" and "scope:" have to be repeated for each IP meantioned in the routes list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you add loop over ROUTES variable

```
- name: vartest
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    ROUTES:
      - ip: "aaa.AAA.aaa.AAA"
      - ip: "bbb.BBB.bbb.BBB"
      - ip: "ccc.CCC.ccc.CCC" 
  tasks: 
    - name: display
      template:
        src: test.j2 
        dest: test.conf
```

template file:

```
        :
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: {{ ansible_default_ipv4.gateway }}
          on-link: true
{% for rec in ROUTES %}
        - to: {{ rec.ip }}/32
          scope: link
{% endfor %}
```

be careful to begin the loop jinja2 at the begining of line to avoid whitespace before the string

result in result file:

```
  routes:
    - to: 0.0.0.0/0
      via: 10.0.2.2
      on-link: true
    - to: aaa.AAA.aaa.AAA/32
      scope: link
    - to: bbb.BBB.bbb.BBB/32
      scope: link
    - to: ccc.CCC.ccc.CCC/32
      scope: link
```

Comment: Man, you did it. This is exact the type of ansible code I needed. I didn't know that looping inside templates will also work.
I keep that in my mind for future projects. Thanks a lot!